# How do I echo a sum of a variable and a number?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have a variable `x=7` and I want to echo it plus one, like `echo ($x+1)` but I'm getting:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected
>   token `$x+1'

How can I do that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No need for `expr`, POSIX shell allows `$(( ))` for arithmetic evaluation:

```
echo $((x+1))
```

See [**§2.6.4**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04)

Answer (score 5):

Try double parentheses:

```
$ x=7; echo $(($x + 1))
8
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `bc` utility:

```
$ x=3;
$ echo "$x+5.5" | bc
8.5
```

Answer (score 2):

try
    echo $(($x + 1))

I think that only works on some version of bash that is 3 or more..

```
echo `expr $x + 1`
```

would be another solution

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, `$(( ))` is actually POSIX compliant, not a bash'ism.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo $(($x+1))
8
```

From `man bash`:

> Arithmetic Expansion
>
> Arithmetic expansion allows the evaluation of an  arithmetic
>        expression  and  the substitution of the result.  The format
>        for arithmetic expansion is:
>
> ```
>     $((expression))
> ```
>
> The expression is  treated  as  if  it  were  within  double
>        quotes,  but  a  double  quote inside the parentheses is not
>        treated specially.  All tokens  in  the  expression  undergo
>        parameter expansion, string expansion, command substitution,
>        and quote removal.  Arithmetic substitutions may be nested.
>
> The evaluation is performed according to  the  rules  listed
>        below   under   ARITHMETIC  EVALUATION.   If  expression  is
>        invalid, bash prints a message  indicating  failure  and  no
>        substitution occurs.

Comment: No need to prefix vars with a `$` inside `(( ))`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `expr` command:

```
$ expr $x + 1
8
```

Answer (score 0):

We use `expr` for that:

```
echo `expr $x + 1`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
echo $(( $X + 1 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

echo $((x+1)) also same result as echo $(($x+1))

Comment: Can you please expand on your answer a bit? To the outside observer this seems to be lacking context.